# whole table updates

Tags: mysql, optimization, query-optimization

currently we using MySQL.

We have table with spatial index (so no InnoDB) and doing whole table updates every x seconds (moving object from one place to other).

currently we doing:

```
UPDATE LOW_PRIORITY IGNORE `table`
SET `column1` = CASE `column2`
              WHEN 1 THEN ...
              WHEN 2 THEN ...
              WHEN 3 THEN ...
              ...
              ELSE `column1`
              END;
```

but it gets extremely painful as rows number increases. Is there is better way to do entire table updates? Maybe we should switch to other DB (PostGIS, NoSQL)?

Any thoughts on that?

Comment: Why are you "moving" object(s)? What does this entail? Can you give a real example, instead of your annotated version with all the juicy bits removed for some reason?

Comment: i agree...  moving seems wrong, instead, update a status somewhere.  plus show the actual effort to get actual help.

Comment: I have iphone game Floonr where people can launch virtual balloon and track it on real map. im simulating wind changes at every update depending on lat, lon

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The best way to UPDATE many rows at once is :

- CREATE TEMP TABLE
- Fill it with (primary key, new values) with a big INSERT
- UPDATE table JOIN temptable USING (primary key) SET table.oldvalue=temptable.newvalue

Update :

```
create table test ( id integer primary key, p point not null );
insert into test (id,p) select id, POINT( id%100, floor(id/100) ) from serie limit 10000;
alter table test add spatial index spi (p);
select id, AsText(p) from test;

+----+-------------+
| id | AsText(p)   |
+----+-------------+
|  1 | POINT(1 0)  |
|  2 | POINT(2 0)  |
|  3 | POINT(3 0)  |
...

|  98 | POINT(98 0) |
|  99 | POINT(99 0) |
| 100 | POINT(0 1)  |
| 101 | POINT(1 1)  |
...

|  9999 | POINT(99 99) |
| 10000 | POINT(0 100) |
+-------+--------------+


EXPLAIN SELECT id,AsText(p) from test where Contains( GeomFromText('POLYGON((0 0,0 10,10 10,10 0,0 0))'), p );
+----+-------------+-------+-------+---------------+------+---------+------+------+-------------+
| id | select_type | table | type  | possible_keys | key  | key_len | ref  | rows | Extra       |
+----+-------------+-------+-------+---------------+------+---------+------+------+-------------+
|  1 | SIMPLE      | test  | range | spi           | spi  | 34      | NULL |  112 | Using where |
+----+-------------+-------+-------+---------------+------+---------+------+------+-------------+

create temporary table test2 ( id integer primary key, p point not null );
insert into test2 (id,p) select id, POINT( 1+(id%100), 1+floor(id/100) ) from serie limit 10000;
update test, test2 set test.p=test2.p where test.id=test2.id;

EXPLAIN SELECT id,AsText(p) from test where Contains( GeomFromText('POLYGON((0 0,0 10,10 10,10 0,0 0))'), p );
+----+-------------+-------+-------+---------------+------+---------+------+------+-------------+
| id | select_type | table | type  | possible_keys | key  | key_len | ref  | rows | Extra       |
+----+-------------+-------+-------+---------------+------+---------+------+------+-------------+
|  1 | SIMPLE      | test  | range | spi           | spi  | 34      | NULL |  102 | Using where |
+----+-------------+-------+-------+---------------+------+---------+------+------+-------------+
```

No problem here (MySQL 5.1.41)

Comment: Looks interesting, will try that

Comment: Hm, it seems such kind of update not working with spatial indexes. If i include indexed column i always getting error: '#126 - Incorrect key file for table 'tablename.MYI'; try to repair it' and repairing don't help. If i remove spatial index, everything seems to work

Comment: did you had spatial index in test table?

Comment: Hm, the error message #126 was particularly helpful eh ! When I try to create a spatial index on a nullable column, I get "ERROR 1252 (42000): All parts of a SPATIAL index must be NOT NULL". So perhaps your version of mysql is old/buggy ?

Comment: i have 5.1.52 (latest default on amazon cloud). And yes - error not very helpful :) I got it not when trying to create but when i try to push records back (last step)